# Finding files and directories with different umask

Tags: find, chmod

I have an umask as a `0002` using `umask -S` it returns `u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx`.

How do I find all files and directories that does not have rights set up according to mask?

The directories goes `777 - mask`
and files `666 - mask`
If i do something like

```
find . ! -perm $(umask -S)
```

it will find all files/directories that does not have rights set to `u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx` ( 777 - 002 are there rights but 666 - 002 are different rights) which is good for directories, but not for files.

How do I find files, that have different rights than current set umask ?

example

```
 touch one
 ls -l
 -rw-rw-r-- 1 trolkura trolkura 0 kvě  4 09:01 one
```

umask is 0002 so this results in `664` , but when I do

```
find . -type f ! -perm $(umask -S)
./one
```

result shows newly created file because it is looking for files that does not have `775` rights (Directory rights).

Comment: According to your question, you wanna search all files which doesn't have 0662 permission right ?

Comment: 0664 but yes  i do

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try this one :

```
find . -user trolkura ! -perm -u+rw
```

This means: look for files starting in present directory, owned by trolkura, where the permissions for group and other can be anything (- in front of permission string) and the users permissions are only: rw

Answer (score 0):

You can use the octal forms and do the calculations by hand. With a POSIX shell:

```
dir_perms=$(printf '%#o' "$((0777 - $(umask)))")
non_dir_perms=$(printf '%#o' "$((dir_perms & 0666))")
find . -type d ! -perms "$dir_perms" -o ! -type d ! -perms "$non_dir_perms"
```

The output format of `umask` alone is not specified by POSIX but in practice, will all shells, it's an octal number with at least one leading 0.

`zsh` doesn't treat numbers with leading 0s as octal by default. In `zsh`, you can either enable `sh` emulation in a local context for that (`(){ emulate -L sh; ....}` or `(emulate sh; ...)` or just `set -o octalzeroes`) or use:

```
dir_perms=0$(([##8] 8#777 - 8#$(umask)))
non_dir_perms=0$(([##8] 8#$dir_perms & 8#666))
```

With `mksh` that doesn't treat numbers with leading 0s as octal by default either, you can use `set -o posix` or do:

```
dir_perms=$(printf '%#o' "$((8#777 - 8#$(umask)))")
non_dir_perms=$(printf '%#o' "$((8#$dir_perms & 8#666))")
```

Comment: Could you please explain the code for the OP?